# QML QuickControls2 custom color themes

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm using `Material` style in my app. I know how to switch between themes using `qtquickcontrols2.conf` file:

```
[Controls]
Style=Material

[Universal]
Theme=Dark
Accent=Red

[Material]
Theme=Dark
Primary=Gray
Accent=#825AA7
```

But let say that I want to have predefined Material's themes like: pink, green, blue. Each one has own pedefined colors for `Primary`, `Accent` etc. User should be able to change between these themes at runtime. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand you, you want to change colors at runtime.

In your code you should add this. It uses property variables `globalColor` and `globalTheme`. *(You could rename these if you want)*

```
Material.accent: Material.color(globalColor)
Material.theme: globalTheme

property string globalColor: Material.Blue   
property int globalTheme: Material.Light
```

If you need to change the color or theme *(Dark, Light)*, you have to change the values of properties `globalColor` and `globalTheme`.

Also, if you need to save color and theme, you could add this piece of code in **[Settings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html)** *(as in the example below)* to save the value in the application settings.

```
Settings {
    property string globalColor: Material.Blue
    property int globalTheme: Material.Light
}
```